# Series with complex numbers

Tags: analysis

I have a series $$\sum_{k=0}^{∞}  k^{14}\frac{2^k+3^ki}{(4i)^k}$$

What rule do I use here if I'm trying to find out if it converges or not? Because I can't get an answer with anything ratio, root, nth. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What are you doing with the series? Are you trying to establish convergence? Are you trying to find its sum?

Comment: Looking for Convergence

Comment: I would split it into two sums, $\sum k^{14} \frac{2^k}{(4i)^k}$ and $\sum k^{14} \frac{3^k i }{(4i)^k}$, and apply ratio test separately.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{∞}=  k^{14}$? Is the equal sign a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivatives may be a (uncommon but useful) tool in the present case :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^{14}\frac{2^k+i3^k}{(4i)^k} 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^{14}}{\mathrm{d}z^{14}}\right|_{z=0} \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{kz}\frac{2^k+i3^k}{(4i)^k} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^{14}}{\mathrm{d}z^{14}}\right|_{z=0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2e^z}{4i}\right)^k + i\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{3e^z}{4i}\right)^k\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^{14}}{\mathrm{d}z^{14}}\right|_{z=0} \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{4i}e^z} + \frac{i}{1-\frac{3}{4i}e^z}\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \left.\left(\frac{f(z)}{(1-\frac{2}{4i}e^z)^{14}} + \frac{g(z)}{(1-\frac{3}{4i}e^z)^{14}}\right)\right|_{z=0}
\end{array} 
$$
with $f,g$ non-singular functions. This expression is perfectly defined at $z=0$ and thus the sum is convergent.

But the ratio test can still do the job :
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{14}\left(\frac{a}{4i}\right)^{k+1}}{k^{14}\left(\frac{a}{4i}\right)^k} = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a}{4i}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{14} = \frac{a}{4i}
$$
where $a=2$ or $3i$, hence $|\frac{a}{4i}|<1$ and convergence.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying with the ratio, but I get (2i^k +3i^k)/4i^k+1 +2((k+1)^14/k^14)) any advice on how to move on from here

Comment: @Troldino I'll add a the ratio test in an edit soon ;)

Comment: Oooooh now I get it, thank you so much!!